# Bundler takes forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, bundler

I just installed Ubuntu 13 and trying to get Rails to work. I've installed RVM, Ruby and Rails 4 properly. After that I cloned my project from github and ran `bundle install` in my project.

What happens next is that it takes **Ages** to complete bundling. So long that it even times out and is still running now after 15 minutes.

Do I need to update my bundler or something? If so, How?

Comment: Just cancel and try again server or network issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably either you have network problem, or the gem server is down. If it is the former, then fix it. If it is the latter, then wait until it is working.

Comment: +1. Run some network speed tests to make sure the connection is good. Ping the gem servers and see what speed is available over TCP, not UDP.

Answer (score 2):

The **current pre-release** Bundler version (`gem install bundler --pre`) allows you to paralellize the installation of gems:

```
bundle install --jobs 4
```

You may also use the default configuration option:

```
bundle config --global jobs 4
```